# getaddrinfo: xxURL get result from proxy gai_error = 0

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework

Im building a flutter application which uses django ad back-end. using signup api endpoint. the
api shows error 200 from the logs but signup doesnt go through.
the logs

```
D/libc-netbsd( 8600): getaddrinfo: hookie-twitter.herokuapp.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/flutter ( 8600): 200
```

**sign up service**

```
  Future<int> authUserSignup(String username, String password,
  String email) async {
http.Response response = await http.post(
    signUpUrl,
    body: {
      "username": username,
      // "phone":phone,
      "password": password,
      "email": email,

    }
);
print(response.statusCode);
return response.statusCode;

}

on signup onClicK
 _pressCreateAccountButton(){
//TO DO: MOVE TO VERIFY PHONE SECTION
var signMeUp = connectSigninApi.authUserSignup(editControllerName.text, editControllerEmail.text, editControllerPassword2.text);
 if(signMeUp == 200){
   if(_globalformkey.currentState.validate() && matchesEmail.hasMatch(editControllerEmail.text)){
     if(editControllerPassword1.text == editControllerPassword2.text){
       print("User pressed \"CREATE ACCOUNT\" button");
       print("Login: ${editControllerName.text}, E-mail: ${editControllerEmail.text}, "
           "password1: ${editControllerPassword1.text}, password2: ${editControllerPassword2.text}");
       route.push(context, "/sendphone");
       Toast.show('sign successrgb',context,gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
     }
   }
 }
else{
  Toast.show('sign failedbik',context,gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
 }
}
```

Comment: Check your endpoints for errors.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP response "200" only indicates that the request has succeeded. It's best to check the logs of the backend to see if a response has been made. The log with `getaddrinfo` seems to be a warning and doesn't provide enough details for us to work with. Check what the `response.body` contains if there's any meaningful results.

But glancing at your code snippet, it seems that you just need to add `await` when `Future` has been set to the var.

```dart
var signMeUp = await connectSigninApi.authUserSignup(...)
```

Without `await`, the method will be called but it won't wait for the result.